# You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My React app has two radio buttons, on
whose click I am changing the label and length of an input field. I’m getting this error:

> Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

```
<Row className="pb-3">
     <Col xs="1"> <BrInput type="radio" id="faNum" value="faNum" onChange={this.handleRadioSelect} checked={faRrLabel === 'faNum' ? true : false} /> </Col>
     <Col xs="2"> <BrLabel styleClass="ml-sm-0" element='FA No.' textSize={textSize} textBold={true} /></Col>
     <Col xs="1"> <BrInput type="radio" id="rrNum" value="rrNum" onChange={this.handleRadioSelect} checked={faRrLabel === 'rrNum' ? true : false} /> </Col>
     <Col xs="2"> <BrLabel styleClass="ml-sm-0" element='RR Code' textSize={textSize} textBold={true} /></Col>
</Row>
```

Here is my `handleRadioSelect` function.

```
handleRadioSelect = (value) => {
    this.setState({ faRrLabel: value })
}
```

Comment: You need to add defaultChecked attribute to your checkbox

Comment: Tip: `faRrLabel === 'faNum' ? true : false` is equivalent to `faRrLabel === 'faNum'`. What’s a `BrInput`? Does it do the right thing with `onChange`?

Comment: this way you mean?   defaultChecked ={faRrLabel === 'faNum' ? true : false}

Comment: case "radio":
        return (
          <RadioWrapper
            type='radio'
            id={this.props.id}
            name={this.props.name}
            value={this.props.value}
            checked={this.props.checked}
            onClick={this.handleRadioSelect}
          />
        );